# Проблема с OpenGraph

Tags: разметка

Проблема заключается в следующем: сделал og разметку на странице; гугл+, вк, одноклассники и твитер воспринимают все как надо, в вот фэйсбук не правильно принимает значение og:title, а именно из вразы берет только одно слово, делает его транслит и ставит его с заглавной буквы. Даже не знаю с чем может быть связано, может кто сталкивался. 
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам отвечу. Фейсбук кеширует содержимое, которое он берет в блок поделиться для каждой страницы. Так как og разметка была добавлена позже запуска сайта, часть страниц он уже закешировал с непонятно откуда взятым содержим. Вот сервис, чтобы убрать страницу из кеша фейсбука (вдруг кому пригодится)
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/